# Enabling TabLayout is not enabling onTouchEvents - Tabs not clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

I have simple `TabLayout` with 2 `Tabs`. In one moment I need to disable `TabLayout` and disable user interaction with `Tabs` too.

But if I want to enable them again, it is not working. Tab indicator and alpha is changed back to normal, but tabs are not reacting to user interaction.

`select()` function is reacting with listener normally, only physical interaction with Tabs on screen is not working.

Anyone have this problem?

Functions to enable/disable `Tabs` (some parts are just visual change to disable state - `TabLayout` will not grey out if you disable it like `Button`)

```
private fun deactivateTabs(){
        tabs.apply {
            selectTab(null)
            isEnabled = false
            touchables?.forEach {
                it.isEnabled = false
                it.alpha = .5f
            }
            setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(tabs.context, R.color.grey))
        }
    }

    private var lastSelected: Int = -1
    private fun activateTabs(){
        tabs.apply {
            isEnabled = true
            touchables?.forEach {
                it.isEnabled = true
                it.alpha = 1f
            }
            setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(tabs.context, R.color.colorTab))

            if (lastSelected == -1){
                //default tab
                getTabAt(0)?.select()
            } else {
                getTabAt(lastSelected)?.select()
            }
        }
    }
```

Also `childCount` is different from `tabCount` in my `TabLayout` which is totally weird behavior in Android. I added tabs to my layout xml inside `TabLayout` so it should be counted as its children. but `childCount` is 1 and `tabCount` is 2.

I dont get this behavior at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few hours I solved this issue by saving `Tabs` as touchable `Views`.

I could not change state directly. I had to save touchables, which created clone (with pointer). And I changed those instead of real ones.

Updated code:

```
private fun deactivateTabs(){
        tabs.apply {
            tabsAsTouchables = touchables
            tabsAsTouchables.forEach {
                it.isEnabled = false
                it.alpha = .5f
            }
            setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(tabs.context, R.color.grey))
        }
    }

    private var lastSelected: Int = -1
    private var tabsAsTouchables: List<View> = emptyList()
    private fun activateTabs(){
        tabs.apply {
            tabsAsTouchables.forEach {
                it.isEnabled = true
                it.alpha = 1f
            }
            setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(tabs.context, R.color.colorTab))

            if (lastSelected == -1){
                //default tab
                getTabAt(TAB_HISTORY)?.select()
            } else {
                getTabAt(lastSelected)?.select()
            }
        }
    }
```